# Remove persistent devices from file browser list

Tags: browser, udev, devices

In my file browser, it lists all the drives and devices available for browsing. There is one that is from another OS installation, and I want to remove it from the list.

Hiding devices using `/etc/udev/rules.d/` works for other devices I want to hide, except this one.

The UUID for the device is different from the ones for the partitions.

```
$ sudo blkid
```

-shows this device is associated with the device mapper.

deleting the link in `/dev/mapper/relevant-link-name` didnt work because device mapper made another very quickly.

How can I hide this device from the file browser?

Answer (score 1):

Using `lvdisplay`, `vgscan`, `vgremove` as @user195059 suggests probably works, but they are in the [lvm2 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/lvm2) which I no longer have installed.

Instead I used

```
$ sudo dmsetup info
```

which showed "Name: *unwantedDevice*" of my unwanted `/dev/mapper/`*unwantedDevice* and "State: ACTIVE". I unmounted the device (from its menu in the Unity panel), then issued

```
$ sudo dmsetup remove unwantedDevice
```

and it looks like it took. I also ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

Answer (score 0):

Device mapper creates references to partitions or devices, and associates a UUID that is different to the one seen in partition managers. Its not a new or separate device, its just a new reference.

The file browser will display this device, even if it is hidden by a rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/

Use the file browser to get the UUID of the device, via properties.

List all the devices and find the one with that UUID, find out its name:

```
$ sudo blkid
```

If the device you want to hide is associated with the device mapper, ie /dev/mapper/device-name    you can proceed to remove that reference by following the instructions below.

List the LVM devices to see if that device appears:

```
$ sudo lvdisplay
```

If so, then list the device mapper groups to see if it matches:

```
$ sudo vgscan
```

If so, then delete that group (change groupname to yours, no quotes):

```
$ sudo vgremove groupname
```

The device should no longer appear in your browser, even after restarting.